# Reprogram Marlin to assign endstop pins to arbitrary tasks [Arduino Mega]

Tags: marlin, endstop

Can someone point me out an appropriate entry code for this task in Marlin source code?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, given one

- has already enabled `USE_<AXIS>_PLUG` (for example 
  `<AXIS> = XMIN`) in Marlin's `Configuration.h`,
- one can add an additional `define` (for example `<AXIS>_ENDSTOP_CUSTOM`) in
  `Configuration.h` and
- make this [block](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/0110faa717e642574ade9eb7aed250ee2840e942/Marlin/endstops.cpp#L637) the `else` statement in an
  `<AXIS>_ENDSTOP_CUSTOM` existence check, with the positive case being your
  arbitrary task.

The function that gets executed in the standard case in the linked block is `PROCESS_ENDSTOP`, so cloning it would be a good starting point to make a `PROCESS_ENDSTOP_CUSTOM` task, too.

Comment: Interesting - presumably you could then execute both the current endstop task (stop moving, indicate zero, etc) and some new tasks (launch cruise missiles, start playing Fast& Furious on the large-screen monitor).